# Dynamic component subscriptions in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am rendering some dynamic components through a **ngFor** loop and I want to have the possibility for those components to communicate with each other. My first idea of doing this is to have a subscribe for some **Subject** changes from a helper state service (**myComunicationService**) :

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of dataList">
    <custom-component [entry]="entry"/>
</div>
```

**Custom component ts**

```
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() entry: Entry;

  private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private myComunicationService: MyComunicationService) {}

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.unsubsribe();
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.myComunicationService.dataChanged$.subscribe(
        (dataChanged) => {
          if (isForThisComponentInstance(dataChanged)) {
            // do stuff for this component instance only
          }
        }
      );
    );
  }

  // private isForThisComponentInstance = (dataChanged) => boolean
  // this method checks some unique property that matches with the instance component

}
```

So basically all my components are listening to the same event, all of them are catching that event and the **if { }** statement is some kind of filter that actually allows the component to change / do things. ( not very happy with this approach )

How can I improve this and not depend on the if statement ?

Comment: What type is `dataChanged`? With classes you could check for a specific class using `instanceof`. The angular router uses a similiar system https://angular.io/api/router/Event

Comment: You will have that `if` in one for or another here or there. You can change eg `if` statement to `filter` and `pipe` it along. Using thjat you can expose dedicated service methods that will filter out all other events. But all of that is just a different name for the same thing.

Comment: @Antoniossss I understand your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using

`this.myComunicationService.dataChanged$` directly in your component, you can ask the service to do some extra work for you.

Say `this.myComunicationService.getChangesFor(this)`

Then in your service

```
getChangesFor(compy: CustomComponent): Observable<any>{
  return this.dataChanged$.pipe(
    filter(data => data.id === compy.id)
  );
}
```

This is really just the same thing, but with the logic removed from the component where it probably doesn't really belong. This way if 10 different components all call this service, they don't all implement this logic separately. It also gives you the freedom to change how the communications service deals with the problem.

For example:

1. You may create a new Subject/ReplaySubject for each component (and, for example, shove them in an array). Then instead of filtering, target only the components that you know will (or might) want the data.
2. You may define a nomenclature and/or interface that is component agnostic which decides which types of data are appropriate to filter.

At some point or another, however, the logic of which data goes where is up to you.

Comment: Makes totally sense, a clean approach. Thank you so much for the reply and detailed explanation.